# How to send SSL Certificate with CURL? Server says "Error: Access is Denied. Client SSL Certificate Required"

Tags: ssl, curl

Server asks me to send with every request a SSL Certificate. I try the following curl operation:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cert cert.p12:password -X POST -d 'jsonBody' https://api.server.com
```

But the server response me:

```
Error: Access is Denied. Client SSL Certificate Required.
```

Why? :(

UPDATE:

```
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

Comment: The exact format of the certificate file depends on the SSL engine. Please add output from `curl --version` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Steffen. Here you are: curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets

Comment: Please add the details to your question and not to a comment. Apart from that it should work because it is SecureTransport, so it might still be that the certificate is not the one that the server expects. To check that the certificate was actually sent you can do a packet capture and look at the TLS handshake with wireshark. The certificate should be sent in the ClientCertificate message after the client got the ServerHello.

Comment: Sorry Steffen :). By the way I installed Wireshark (nice software, thanks!) and... I don't find ClientCertificate, after Server Hello i see "Certificate" and after that "Client Key Exchange, Certificate Verify, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message" and after "Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message"

Comment: Please look what is sent in which direction. The Certificate from the server should be sent into the direction of the client (as part of the ServerHello), while the certificate from the client should be sent to the server. If no certificate is sent from the client to the server then something is wrong with your cert option. If the certificate is sent then the server does not accept this certificate - in this case look for error messages at the server side.

Comment: (+@Steffen) *client* cert should be after ServerHelloDONE. But CertVerify is only used for client auth, so client clearly sent *some* cert. Look inside the Certificate message that is immediately before CertVerify to see if it is the (or a?) *correct* cert.